# Rotate class of div elements every reload

Tags: jquery

I have a working code right here that randomly adds **kvDisplay** class on a list of divs every page load. The code below is particularly for 3 divs only.

```
var classes = ["kvDisplay", " ", " "];
classes.sort(function(){ return Math.random() - .5 });

$("#keyvisual .kvWrapper").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass(classes.pop());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m71xc5ty/

Instead of adding class randomly, how do I change it in a specific order?

Ex. Class **kvDisplay** will be added to the first child div of #keyvisual on first pageload, then it will be added to the second child on the next reload, and so on. If the kvDisplay class is on the third/last child, the class will go back to the first child after reload.

Comment: you can not keep track of the number of page loads with only javascript .  You will need to store a variable on the server or in a cookie , session, local storage , etc

Comment: How about javascript cookie? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Scott & Jaya: I see. Thanks! I'll look into it, but I'm not really quite familiar with using cookies. How do work on it with the current code I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie plugin to use cookies with jquery.

This code will help you to achieve it:

```
if ($.cookie("classes")) { 
    var classes = JSON.parse($.cookie('classes'));
} else {
    var classes = ["kvDisplay1", "kvDisplay2", "kvDisplay3"];
}
console.log(classes);
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $("#keyvisual .kvWrapper").each(function(){
      $(this).addClass(classes[i]);
      console.log(classes[i]);
      i++;
    });
    var a = classes[0];
    classes.shift();
    classes.push(a);
    $.cookie("classes", JSON.stringify(classes));
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Tried it and this is exactly what I needed! :)